# How to access Bluetooth device after receiving ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm connecting to a Bluetooth device using `connectGatt()` with `autoConnect=true`. If the connection is lost and the device re-appears and re-connects, I get an `ACL_CONNECTED` intent from my `BroadcastReceiver`. However, I'm not clear on how I'm supposed to access the device to write/read data at this point.

Normally, I call `connectGatt()` with a `BluetoothGattCallback`. When the device is connected, the bluetooth stack gives me a `BluetoothGatt` which I can then use to access the device (e.g. BluetoothGatt.discoverServices()`.

But with autoconnect, when I receive `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` the device is already connected. If I call `connectGatt()` again, the stack ends up returning two copies of everything, so I think I shouldn't call `connectGatt()` again. However, if I don't, how I do get a `BluetoothGatt` object to access the device?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out calling `connectGatt()` is the correct thing to do. The reason I was getting multiple copies is because the previous `BluetoothGatt` object lingered around. In order to allow auto-connect to work, that first `BluetoothGatt` object had to be kept. What worked for me is to keep that object until I get `ACL_CONNECTED`, close that object, and then create a new callback.